# Google Cloud Storage - BrokenPipeError when uploading using Python library

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-python

I have a long-running Python script that uploads documents from MongoDB to GC Storage. Documents are first exported to local csv file and that csv file is uploaded to GC Storage.

Before the error, the script was running for about 10 hours with no problems. What caused this error?

Code where I use GCS:

```
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(KEY_JSON)

def upload_file(filepath):
    bucket = client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
    blob = bucket.blob(filepath)
    blob.upload_from_filename(filepath)

    logging.info("Uploaded file {} to GCS.", str(filepath))
```

Stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/leonz/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/leonz/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 357, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1107, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1152, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1103, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 936, in _send_output
    self.send(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 908, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 899, in sendall
    v = self.send(data[count:])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 869, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 594, in write
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```